# Do other Earths think of themselves as the “Prime Earth”?

Tags: dc, comics, the-new-52, dc-rebirth

In DC Comics continuity, there is currently a pretty big multiverse. In it, the main earth is Prime Earth. There are a lot of them, like Earth-23 with a black Superman as the president of the United States and the very spooky Earth-13 with Superdemon as its protector.

This seems like very prime-earth-centric terminology. Do other continuities’ inhabitants view their worlds as Earth-0 and as the main world, as far as we know based on comics?

Comment: Have the alternative universe counterparts of one character ever came to together and agreed upon what to call their respective universes?

Comment: I believe in one of the CW Flash episodes Harrison Wells from Earth 2 says something along the lines of "you are Earth 2 to us".

Comment: For fairness' sake, would you go with something like 'Earth 1', 'Earth Prime', 'Earth A', 'Earth Alpha', etc?

Comment: We on *Earth* will graciously allow you on *[Earth'](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime.html)* and *[Earth''](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoublePrime.html)* to acknowledge yourself as secondary and tertiary.

Comment: It struck me as odd in the Flash show when characters would appear and say things like "I'm from Earth-2" or "I'm from Earth-3". How did they even know which Earth they're from?

Answer (score 7):

The only moment I can bring to mind is not strictly DC canon.  (But then, after never-ending reboots, what **is** canon?)  The image below is from the epic "Avengers/JLA" crossover event and neither side looks to be conceding to the label of "Earth-Two".

[image]